# How to handle void* parameter lists holding large buffers under Go 1.6's CGo pointer rules

Tags: go, cgo

Suppose I'm interacting with a third party C library from Go that maintains some complicated data structure. It allows me to iterate over the data structure using an API that looks something like this:

```
typedef void (*callback)(double x, void *params);
iterate(int64_t start_idx, int64_t end_idx, callback f, void *params);
```

With the idea being that `iterate` loops over every index between `start_idx` and `end_idx` and calls `f` on every element in that range. If you wanted to read the data out of the complicated data structure and into an array, you would write something like this:

```
typedef struct buffer {
    double *data;
    int64_t i;
} buffer;

void read_callback(double x, void *params) {
    buffer *buf = (buffer*) params;
    buf->data[i] = x;
    buf->i++;
}
```

Now let's suppose that I wanted to wrap this API call in a Go function where the user passes the function a pre-allocated buffer. In Go 1.5, I might have done something like this:

```
func Read(startIdx, endIdx int64, data []float64) {
    buf := &C.buffer{}
    buf.data = unsafe.Pointer(&data[0])
    C.iterate(C.int64_t(startIdx), C.int64_t(endIdx),
        (C.callback)(C.read_callback), unsafe.Pointer(buf))
}
```

However, in Go 1.6 this is invalid. `data` is a Go-pointer and so is `buf`, meaning that the runtime panics to prevent a GC error. Allocating `buf` as a C-pointer is also not allowed. I think the intended way to handle something like this would be to allocate `data` as a C pointer, but I don't want to allocate a temporary array inside `Read` because these arrays are large enough that I can't hold two of them in memory at once (and even if I could, I wouldn't be able to deal with the heap fragmentation).

My current (very hacky) solutions are to either pass some of the data around as global variables or to pack `i` and the array length in the first element of array (and then to swap some data around at the end of the iteration). Is there a way for me to do this which is less terrible?

Comment: From the [cgo rules for passing pointers](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Passing_pointers) state: "C code may not keep a copy of a Go pointer after the call returns." and "Go code may not store a Go pointer in C memory". You can't do this using a callback pattern, since it needs to store the pointer and the function returns immediately. Can you allocate and keep all the data in C from the start?

Comment: I don't think I'm storing any Go pointers in C memory. Can you elaborate? I can't keep the data in C from the start, either.

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that `C.iterate` was asynchronous, storing the pointer while it operated. Try making a C wrapper function that only takes the data pointer and indexes, then allocs the buffer and calls iterate for you. This way you're not passing a "pointer to a struct containing a pointer"